# Convert Date field for Oracle GoldenGate

Tags: oracle-golden-gate

I have an Oracle GoldenGate setup with Oracle database as my source and a non-Oracle target. My source database is in Timezone A. Is there a way to configure my Extract/Replicat so that all data in my target is in UTC or some customizable Timezone B?

To make it clearer, suppose i have a database in EST where I have a date column with value `2018-11-26 17:01:49` I want the data to be converted to UTC and the replicated value would be `2018-11-26 22:01:49`. Is there a clean(or any) way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This conversion only works on a **REPLICAT**. It does a full calculation of times and goes from a source date column named `dt` to a target column named `dt5` that is to be converted to the date + 5 hours (you can adjust it to whatever time zone you must convert the data). It assumes your source table is `t4` and target table is `t4_copy` (for SCHEMA `scratch`)

```
MAP scratch.t4, TARGET scratch.t4_copy,
COLMAP ( USEDEFAULTS,
dt5 = @DATE ('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS', 'JTS',
@COMPUTE (@DATE ('JTS', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS', dt) + 18000000000 ) ) 
);
```

`JTS` (Juilan timestamp) produce numbers you can use in numeric expressions. The unit is microseconds (that's why the `+18000000000`)

Comment: I don't think this would work in my case.
1. I want this conversion to happen or all tables, without having to map each and every table/field manually.
2. The offset should be from one timezone to another. This conversion would change based on daylight saving. Son having a fixed offset value would not work.

Comment: Well there are PRESERVETARGETTIMEZONE and SOURCETIMEZONE parameters you can use, but I'm pretty sure these are only for metadata in the trail files. So unless the data is tied to that metadata, I doubt it will change without transformation. In any case you must specify which columns you want transformed (what if you have some date/timestamp columns you don't want transformed?). If you want all date columns transformed you could do `SELECT column_name FROM all_tabs_columns WHERE data_type ='DATE' AND owner = 'scratch';` and find a way to replace `dt5` with the input of that